# How to execute a bash script from null resource terraform azure

Tags: bash, azure-devops, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-azure

I want to run a .sh script

```
  resource "null_resource" "Add_pipeline_Stages2" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
      command= "chmod +x ${path.cwd}/../Terraform-Scripts/addpipelinestage.sh"
      interpreter = ["bash", "-command"] 

    }
    depends_on = [null_resource.iac_Configuration]
  }
```

but I got this error:

```
bash: line 0: bash: chmod +x /home/vsts/work/1/s/Terraform/templates/../Terraform- 
Scripts/addpipelinestage.sh: invalid option name
```

Comment: What is in the script?

Comment: The script contain sed commands and az run pipeline commands

Comment: Ok, and can you change in the `interpreter` from `-command` to `-c`?

Comment: (local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-c" "chmod +x /home/vsts/work/1/s/Terraform/templates/../Terraform-Scripts/addpipelinestage.sh"]


Got this output.

Comment: @MarkoE The null resource completion done in Apply stage. But I donot get the output of script and any result of my script, what i want to do.

Comment: Ah, so you want to execute the script?

Comment: @MarkoE Yes i want to execute the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the script needs to be invoked after changing it to be executable, here is what needs to change:

```
resource "null_resource" "Add_pipeline_Stages2" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "chmod +x ${path.cwd}/../Terraform-Scripts/addpipelinestage.sh; ${path.cwd}/../Terraform-Scripts/addpipelinestage.sh"
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
  }
  depends_on = [null_resource.iac_Configuration]
}
```